# Set up ActiveMQ in TomEE

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, apache-tomee

How can I configure TomEE (conf/openejb.xml) to do the following:

- Enable ActiveMQ
- Set the ActiveMQ host and port
- Create a JMS queue and topic

Comment: I'd hate to go to Google and search for simple JMS tutorials when you can do it yourself.

Comment: I've done it myself - all day long. Setting up a JMS queue is relatively straight forward, I get that. I am just struggling to do it in TomEE as it isn't very well documented.

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation](http://tomee.apache.org/documentation.html) and the [the examples](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/index.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is directly from the documentation, how to set up JMS resources. I don't understand why it was difficult for you to find this, I found it in 5 seconds.
Sending/receiving messages is not specific to TomEE, you can find many examples for that.

```
<tomee>
    <Resource id="MyJmsResourceAdapter" type="ActiveMQResourceAdapter">
        BrokerXmlConfig =  broker:(tcp://someHostName:61616)
        ServerUrl       =  tcp://someHostName:61616
    </Resource>

    <Resource id="MyJmsConnectionFactory" type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory">
        ResourceAdapter = MyJmsResourceAdapter
    </Resource>

    <Container id="MyJmsMdbContainer" ctype="MESSAGE">
        ResourceAdapter = MyJmsResourceAdapter
    </Container>

    <Resource id="FooQueue" type="javax.jms.Queue"/>
    <Resource id="BarTopic" type="javax.jms.Topic"/>
</tomee>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after. Thank you